# Best Options to manage large sets of data SQlserver

Tags: sql-server, database-design, etl

I am currently working on a project which involves the following:

- The application I am working on  is connected to a SQlserver
  database.
- SAP loads information into multiple tables (in a daily
  and also hourly basis) into a MASTER database
- There are 5 other databases(hosted on the same server) that access this information via synonyms and stored procedure calls to the MASTER database
- The MASTER database  purely used for storing the data and routing it to the other databases)

  **Master Database** -

  Tables:
- `MASTER_TABLE1 <------- SAP inserts data into this table.Triggers are used  to process the  valid data & insert into secondary staging tables  -say MASTER_TABLE1_SEC`
- `MASTER_TABLE1_SEC  -- Holds processed data coming into MASTER_TABLE1`

FIVE other databases ( for each manufacturing facility) are present in the same server. My application is connected to the facility databases ( not the Master)
FACILITY1
Facility2
....
FACILITY5

Synonyms of `MASTER_TABLE1_SEC` are created in each of these 5 facility databases
Stored procedures are again called from the Facility databases- in order to load data from the `MASTER_TABLE1_SEC` into the respective tables(  within EACH facility) based on the business logic.

Is there a better architecture to handle this kind of a project? I am a beginner when it comes to advanced data management. Can anyone suggest a better architecture or tools to handle this?

Comment: This should probably be on dba.stackexchange.com; it goes well beyond the purpose of SO.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of patterns that would actually meet the needs described here.  It serves that you are working with a type of Data Warehouse. I use Data Vault for my Enterprise Data Warehouses.  It is an Ensemble Modeling technique designed for integration and master data preparation. You can think of it as a way to house all data from all time.  You would then generate Data Marts (Kimball Method) for each of the Facilities containing only thei or whatever is required for their needs.